# MySQL claims that I can use columns in SELECT that aren't in GROUP BY, but I can't with equal performance

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, group-by

The MySQL documents state in [section 11.5.3](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) that, despite what the SQL standard may say, it's just fine to use columns in the SELECT clause that aren't in the GROUP BY clause, so long as they are functionally dependent on the grouped key.

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so
>   that you can use nonaggregated columns
>   or calculations in the select list
>   that do not appear in the GROUP BY
>   clause. You can use this feature to
>   get better performance by avoiding
>   unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. For example, you need not
>   group on customer.name in the
>   following query:
>
> ```
> SELECT order.custid, customer.name,
> MAX(payments)   FROM order,customer  
> WHERE order.custid = customer.custid  
> GROUP BY order.custid;
> ```
>
> In standard
>   SQL, you would have to add
>   customer.name to the GROUP BY clause.
>   In MySQL, the name is redundant.

Sounds reasonable. However, though I *can* select those columns, it seems to have an adverse effect on performance.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT o.id FROM objects o GROUP BY o.id;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | range | NULL          | PRIMARY | 3       | NULL | 5262 | Using index for group-by |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

(I realize that this query is pretty silly; it's just the simplest version of a more complex query that has the same issue.) When selecting just the primary key ID I group by, then MySQL uses the primary key index. However, when I include other columns, MySQL does not.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT o.id, o.name FROM objects o GROUP BY o.id;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 5261 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
```

That use of filesort instead of the index really sets me back. I'm currently looking to select `*` from this table, so would like to avoid having to repeat all columns in the group and index them. Is there any way to get MySQL to use the primary key index, as I expect it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it doesn't look like there's a simple answer, I'm going with a cheap solution for the moment.

What I *would* do would be something like the following:

```
SELECT o1.* FROM objects o1 WHERE o1.id IN (SELECT o2.id FROM objects o2 WHERE mycondition GROUP BY o2.id)
```

However, according to how it gets `EXPLAIN`ed, the MySQL optimizer views the subquery as being dependent, which is always a really, really nasty performance killer. I think that's a bug in the query optimizer brought about by the fact that it's the same table, even though it's aliased. As such, I'll be using one query to fetch the IDs, and putting them `IN` the second query that fetches `o.*`. It gets reasonable performance, and isn't *too* painful.

This question is still open to answers with cleaner solutions that perform as well, if not better :)

Answer (score 0):

use a derived table for the group by and join back on whatever table you want to select from

Comment: I can use subqueries and derived tables technically, but the MySQL optimizer in its current form (at least, on the latest version in the Debian repositories) views them as dependent subqueries instead of something to be run ahead of time and then run against. I'm betting it's because it's the same table with different aliases.

Answer (score 0):

In the first query, the only field you're accessing is in an index, so mysql only has to look at the index file.  But in the second query, you're now pulling a column from the table itself which requires also reading the table data.  The first query isn't really using your primary key index the way it might if you had a `WHERE` clause.  It's only using it for the group by, but it's still looking at every entry in the index.

The difference between the first query and the second is just that the second has to look at every row in the full table (aka a table scan), rather than just every primary key value in the index.

As far as optimizing goes, if your real query has no cumulative functions (SUM, COUNT, etc) as in your example then should see a major improvement just doing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.id, o.name FROM objects o
```

However, if that's only true of your simple example and your query really does require a GROUP BY then your next best bet is to increase your [tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) variables to allow for more rows to fit in memory at once.